# Awaited override for non awaited base class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I need to write a virtual base class.

```
public virtual int LoadData()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and need to write a override with await call.

```
public override async Task<int> LoadData()
{
    await Task.Delay(200)
    return 1;
}
```

How this can be implemented?

Comment: This isn't an overriding, it's *overloading*. Overriding means creating a method with the same signature as a virtual method in the base class. In this case the return value is different

Comment: *Why* do you want to override the base method? Callers won't see the overloaded async version anyway and won't be able to call it asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply it's not possible. Cause when you want to override a method, the child-method should has exact name, parameter(s) type (and order), and return type, as the parent one. While, what are you trying to do is overriding `int LoadData()` by `Task<int> LoadData()` which is all wrong (regardless of `async` keyword which has nothing to do here), cause you have two different return-types. So, if you have access to parent's source-code, you have to change your design. For example, one of possible designs can be something like this:

```
// parent:
public virtual Task<int> LoadData()
{
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

// child
public override async Task<int> LoadData()
{
    await Task.Delay(200)
    return 1;
}
```

Or this one:

```
// parent:
public virtual int LoadData()
{
    return 0;
}
public virtual Task<int> LoadDataAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => LoadData());
    // or implement it awaitable; whatever you need, there is no difference.
}

// child
public override int LoadData()
{
    return 0;
}
public override async Task<int> LoadDataAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(200); // or don't await it; just return the Task. whatever is your requirement.
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your base class, you could simply implement a `LoadDataAsync` method:

```
public virtual int LoadData()
{
    return 0;
}

public async Task<int> LoadDataAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => LoadData());
}
```

This leaves you free to override the `LoadData` method in your inherited classes, without the need to implement an asynchronous method.

```
public override int LoadData()
{
    return 69;
}
```

Comment: honestly named methods seems better so i removed my answer ;)